# БД не выводится в web

Tags: java, веб-программирование, sql-server, java-ee, jsp

Хочу вывести таблицу из бд MS SQL в jsp-страницу, вывожу с помощью array list, его же заполняю через отдельный класс с методами, но в сервлете он не заполняется(через отладчик проверял, стопорится на строке с драйвером), соответственно страница пустая выходит, а в консольное приложение через main без проблем...

Comment: "Сторонится на строке с драйвером" - это что означает?

Comment: Что значит `сторонится на строке с драйвером`? И еще покажите код

Comment: Извиняюсь, пишу с телефона не заметил автоисправление, уже все поправил